# Where should cmake files be installed?

Tags: cmake

Where should cmake files be installed? I currently have for the install targets

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.10)
project(projectname)
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
include(GNUInstallDirs)

add_library(projectnameINTERFACE)
target_include_directories(projectnameINTERFACE
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/projectname>
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/>
)


configure_package_config_file(projectnameConfig.cmake.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/projectnameConfig.cmake INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
install(TARGETS projectnameEXPORT projectname-targets)

install(EXPORT projectname-targets FILE projectnameTargets.cmake DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/cmake)
install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/projectnameConfig.cmake DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/cmake)
install(DIRECTORY ./ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/projectname FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h" PATTERN ".git" EXCLUDE)
```

Is the path `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/projectname/cmake` correct?

For Windows builds, it should be installed with `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/libs/project`. When installing it in Linux with `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr` or `/usr/local`, I am not sure if the cmake files should be installed in `/usr/share/cmake` or a similar folder.

In the end, it should work with both methods (`/usr` and `path/to/libdir`) in a reasonable way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the official cmake documentation there are several possibilities where these cmake files should be installed. The location is important in order to find the library using the `find_package()` command. Depending on the platform possible locations are:

```
<prefix>/                                                       (Windows)
<prefix>/(cmake|CMake)/                                         (Windows)
<prefix>/<name>*/                                               (Windows)
<prefix>/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/                                 (Windows)
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/cmake/<name>*/                 (Unix)
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/                       (Unix)
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/         (Unix)
<prefix>/<name>*/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/cmake/<name>*/         (Windows/Unix)
<prefix>/<name>*/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/               (Windows/Unix)
<prefix>/<name>*/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/ (Windows/Unix)
<prefix>/<name>.framework/Resources/                            (macOS)
<prefix>/<name>.framework/Resources/CMake/                      (macOS)
<prefix>/<name>.framework/Versions/*/Resources/                 (macOS)
<prefix>/<name>.framework/Versions/*/Resources/CMake/           (macOS)
<prefix>/<name>.app/Contents/Resources/                         (macOS)
<prefix>/<name>.app/Contents/Resources/CMake/                   (macOS)
```

The prefix is defined by the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable which defaults to `C:/Program Files/${PROJECT_NAME}` on Windows and `/usr/local` on Unix.

On my Arch Linux system most libraries are using the `<prefix>/lib*/cmake/<name>*/` (Unix style) location. For windows personally I would prefer the `<prefix>/cmake` location.

For more detailed information I would recommend you to read the official documentation for your CMake version (for v3.14 see the links in the references below).

*References*:

1. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html
2. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/find_package.html?highlight=find_package#id5

Comment: I think I will use ``<prefix>/share/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake`` then, so it is the same on both platforms and using ``GNUInstallDirs`` the path in the cmake file is  ``${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake``. Not 100% sure about lib or share, but on Linux I am more used to have non-binary files in share.

Comment: Most cmake configurations I have under `<prefix>/lib/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}` are related to Qt and KDE libraries, with all the others in total 231. In `<prefix>/share/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}` are only 9. Most of the libraries I have installed have the `${PROJECT_NAME}` directory inside the cmake directory not vice versa. But as you see from the CMake documentation it's up to you.