# Should I install .cmake files to share/cmake or lib/cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, packaging

In the answer to this question:

[Where should cmake files be installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55845401/1593077)

we learn that, among other places, it is "acceptable" (in terms of CMake's search patterns) to install `.cmake` files under `<prefix>/share/` (perhaps in additional subdirs within) or to `<prefix>/lib/cmake`.

Now, on the one hand, the accepted answer there suggests a preference for `<prefix>/lib/cmake`; but on the other hand, CMake itself, as bundled by most (?) Linux distributions, places its `.cmake` files under `/usr/share/cmake`.

So which option is preferable? Or rather, which is the most commonly-used to your knowledge?

PS - If you use `GNUInstallDirs`, the choice is between `${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake` vs `${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/cmake`, which is perhaps more multi-platformy.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the `.cmake` files:

- for `.cmake` files that are used to import library in a cmake project I would place the `.cmake` files in `<prefix>/lib/cmake`
- for `.cmake` files that may be used to provides macros as are the cmake modules shipped in `/usr/share/cmake`, I would rather use `<prefix>/share/myapp`

The rational is that `/usr/lib` should be used to store platform specific information, while `/usr/share` is for platform independent data. This what is specified in [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf):

> Applications may use a single subdirectory under /usr/lib. If an application uses a subdirectory, all
> architecture-dependent data exclusively used by the application must be placed within that subdirectory.

> The /usr/share hierarchy is for all read-only architecture independent data files.

Comment: But many of the `.cmake` scripts bundled with CMake, under `/usr/share`, are platform specific. CMake doesn't make this distinction. Also, `.cmake` files are not very, or not at all, architecture dependent (e.g. libraries with no architecture-specific compiled parts, and specifically C++ header-only libraries).